# How to auto add/remove checkbox's whether different cells contain value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with the new checkbox feature in google sheets.

In my worksheet, I would like to have a checklist column, **but I want the number of checkboxes to match the number of  rows that have values in the worksheet.**
For example, say column A contains names of workers in the company (that changes from time to time), and column B contains checkboxes, I would like there to be a checkbox in the row, but only if the cell in column A contains a value.

Here is an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKxGzThlMXzJRSGLON8Do4dzJq6HEldcpNTbDzH3Wsw/edit?usp=sharing

How can I do this?

Comment: added spreadsheet example in main post

Comment: @BarkatGuy The link points to a web published spreadsheet. It shows FALSE instead of checkboxes. Is you questions about the new checkbox feature or are you OK by using UNICODE check/unchecked ballot boxes?

Comment: @Rubén Hi, I'm talking about the built-in checkbox's only.

Comment: @BarkatGuy Then the web published spreadsheet doesn't helps. Share your demo spreadsheet with anyone with the link for viewing or add a screenshot.

Comment: @Rubén I Changed the Link to a shareable Demo. Notice Doomd solution, it worked but was to slow on execution so i am searching for a faster solution.     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKxGzThlMXzJRSGLON8Do4dzJq6HEldcpNTbDzH3Wsw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Keep an eye [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria) for "CheckBox". When it becomes available, a script can easily be written.

Comment: Related: [Placing checkboxes in Google Sheets using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50466080/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NEWER (FASTER) BATCH PROCESSING ANSWER:**
My previous answer (see below) was written hastily to illustrate how you could show or hide the new checkboxes based on the contents of another cell. To speed things up, the following new script processes everything into an array, and doesn't update the cells until all of the values are calculated. It still isn't as quick as a built in client side response, but it will handle hundreds or thousands of names within a second or two (so it's ideal for being able to paste in hundreds of names without getting bogged down) and I did try to employ the "best practices" from [this page on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

**Assumptions:**

- You have made a copy of the following example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSnQ1_6Sy018lAoehzQ55QVrfJldoKS5EnWjOxYWxIs/edit?usp=sharing (`File > Make a copy...`)
- Column A is your "Checkboxes" column (see example sheet)
- Column B is your "Names" column (see example sheet)

**Step 1:**
You can skip this step if you've copied the example sheet
Highlight all the relevant cells in your checkboxes column, right click on them, and select "`Data Validation`" from the menu. From the popup dialog box, make sure to select "`Checkbox`" from the Criteria section and then hit "`Save`".

**Step 2:**
If you copied the example sheet, then this script should already be bound to the sheet, otherwise: Insert and save the following script into your script editor "`Tools > Script Editor`." *Note: You may have to approve of the script running as per Google's security permissions.*

```
  function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("New Checkboxes"); //change this to the name of your sheet
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  //var names = ss.getRange("names");//Use this if you are naming the range
  var names = ss.getRange("B3:B");//Use this if you are naming the ranges

  var namesValues = names.getValues(); //Get array of all the names

  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  //var checkboxes = ss.getRange("checkboxes"); //Use this if you are naming the range
  var checkboxes = ss.getRange("A3:A"); //Use this if you want to hard-code your range

  var cbRows = checkboxes.getHeight(); //Get # of rows in the ranges
  var cbValues = checkboxes.getValues(); //Get array of all the checkbox column cell values
  //Logger.log(cbValues);

  var newCBValues = new Array(cbRows); //Create an array to store all the new checkboxes values before we edit the actual spreadsheet

  for (var row = 0; row < cbRows; row++) {
    newCBValues[row] = new Array(0); // Make the array 2 dimensional (even though it only has 1 column, it must be 2D).
    if (namesValues[row] == "" || namesValues[row] == " ") { //If the name cell of this row is empty or blank then...
      newCBValues[row][0] = " "; //Set the value to one space (which will make the cell NOT true or false, and thus NOT display a checkbox).
      //Logger.log("newCBValues[" + row + "][0]: " + newCBValues[row][0]);
    }else{ //otherwise, if the name cell isn't blank...
      if (cbValues[row][0] === true) {
        newCBValues[row][0] = true; //Keep the checkbox checked if it's already checked
      }else{ //If the name cell isn't blank, and it's not true...
        newCBValues[row][0] = false; //Then Keep it or set it to False (an empty checkbox):
      }   
    }
  }
  checkboxes.setValues(newCBValues); // now that we have a completed array of our new checkbox values, let's edit the sheet with them!

}
```

**Step 3:**
Back in the spreadsheet, insert, edit, delete or type in a few names in your names column to see the changes.

That's it!

---

**OLD (SLOW) ANSWER:**
If you don't mind adding a script to your sheet, I figured out how to use the "new" checkboxes, but only show the boxes when you have a corresponding Name in the name column. For the purpose of my script, I did make named ranges of the checkbox column ("checkboxes"), and the names column ("names"). You must also create the same named ranges if you wish to use this script (or just hard code the ranges into the script -- which is not a great way to go if you are going to be changing the size of the range frequently by adding and removing names. Go to the menu `Data > Named ranges...`

Anyway, I created an updated example you can demo on this page: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSnQ1_6Sy018lAoehzQ55QVrfJldoKS5EnWjOxYWxIs/edit#gid=1464332245

You will need to make a copy of this workbook, and then give permission to yourself to use the script below once you add it to your workbook from the menu `Tools > Script Editor`:

```
function onEdit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var names = activeSheet.getRange("names"); //Hard Code the Range here if you don't want to use named ranges (example: "B2:B")
  var checkboxes = activeSheet.getRange("checkboxes"); //Hard Code the Range here if you don't want to use named ranges (example: "A2:A")

  var namesFirstRow = names.getRow();
  var namesLength = names.getLastRow();
  var namesCol = names.getColumn();
  var checkboxesCol = checkboxes.getColumn();

  for (var i=0; i<namesLength; i++) {
    var checkCell = activeSheet.getRange(namesFirstRow+i,checkboxesCol);
    var nameCell = activeSheet.getRange(namesFirstRow+i,namesCol);
    Logger.log(checkCell.getA1Notation() + "  " + nameCell.getA1Notation());

    if (nameCell == "" || nameCell.isBlank()) { //If There is no name in the name column (it's empty or just blank)
      checkCell.setValue(" "); // Make the checkbox column blank so no checkbox appears 
    }else{
      if (checkCell.getValue() === true || checkCell.getValue() === false) {
        //Do nothing since a value is already set
        //app.getUi().alert(checkCell.getA1Notation() + " is " + checkCell.getValue());
      }else{      
        checkCell.setValue("FALSE"); //Place an empty checkbox (FALSE) if a name value has not been set in the name column
      }
    }
  } 

}
```

This will only work if you make sure your "checkboxes" range has already had the data validation selected to the "checkbox" criteria...

Instructions: For the column you need your checkboxes in: highlight the entire range of cells in the column (except for the header), right click on the selected column, choose "Data Validation" and then choose "Checkbox" for the criteria. Then all your "TRUE" and "FALSE" cells will be checked or unchecked checkboxes. Additionally, to integrate all the named ranges that are inside the script, make sure name this checkbox column range "checkboxes" (as per the instructions above).

Comment: Hi! thanks very much for your time. Unfortunately it doesn't create empty checkboxes, instead it creates FALSE cells. I am linking you the format of my spreadsheet (names written in hebrew), so you might see what my problem is. this is with the script and changed names etc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQC64B2_JkIFyX-AxSp43jIyF6wpDDO7BC1bWxXPjK0qaEWSaUi-yEMMwr9IAMBG8TYMUhfRtVIcAKv/pubhtml?gid=1216038915&single=true

Comment: So, the column you need your checkboxes in: highlight the entire column, right click on the selected column, choose "Data Validation" and then choose "Checkbox" for the criteria. Then all your "TRUE" and "FALSE" cells will be checked or unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: thanks for your reply! now your solution works, but only on a non-practical level. In my sheet, it takes about a minute for the checkbox to generate itself, once i enter a value in the names column. I use the sheet for working purposes so i need it to quickly make a checkbox once a value is entered in the name column (let's say that above 5 seconds is too much). 
If you still have energy to help, do you have an idea how to speed things up?

Comment: I added a shareable demo link, if it might help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKxGzThlMXzJRSGLON8Do4dzJq6HEldcpNTbDzH3Wsw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry that these working solutions are not fast enough for you, but I've provided you with two different working answers. Each answer works around the limitations of the new checkbox feature. We understand what you want, but that is not possible right now because the new checkboxes are not objects that are yet referenced in Google Apps scripts documentation.

Comment: @Doomd It's slow because you getRange every row and column. Minimize calls to spreadsheet. The code can be easily optimized to under a second with getValues() and setValues(). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices Furthermore,a single onEdit trigger to a single cell should suffice instead of checking everything on every edit.

Comment: @i-i Fair enough. I mostly banged that out as a proof of concept. I am going to alter that answer to show a better batch processor. Each cell doesn't edit instantly, but I have all the values processes and stored into an array, then write the entire checkbox column after it's done. It's MUCH much faster if you have hundreds or thousands of names

Comment: second script completly destroyed my sheet while first script couldnt maintain checked checkbox if I checked it - it kept uncheck itself

Comment: @JudgeDredd sorry mate...forgot to give the comparison operator THREE  equal signs for the Boolean conditional (ie, "=== TRUE" instead of "== 'TRUE'). I edited the answer with this correction.

Comment: @Doomd Thank you VERY much!! It works great and I'm currently using it at my workplace. I have one last question I promise, I have a couple of sheets and  would like to expand your script to  all of them except the first. how can i do that? :)

Comment: @Doomd wanted to update you that your script is in use and works well on the practical level. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @l'_'l  How would you use the onEdit trigger to optimize? for a single cell it could work, but if the user edits a range it would be a problem. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 19):

not sure if this will help or not. But one way I accomplish this is by using conditional formatting.

Example. If I have entries that go in A2:A and I want to show checkboxes in B2:B ONLY if there is data in the corresponding 'A' cell I do the following;

1. highlight the entire Column from B2:B
2. Insert -> Checkboxes (this will put checkboxes all the way down)
3. Highlight the entire Column of checkboxes
4. Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Custom Formula
5. Input the following custom formula; =ISBLANK($A2)
6. Change the background color and text color to be the same

This will then evaluate the 'A' Column and if it is blank, it will make the background and text color the same (white, for example) and all the checkboxes will 'disappear'. When you input information into column 'A', the checkbox will 'appear'

It's a simple workaround the scripting solutions that works in most cases.

Comment: How could you ensure that checkboxes (either blank or checked) only appear if there is data in adjacent columns? In other words, how can you prevent checkboxes from appearing and going all the way down the column when there is no data in the row?